# CodeBuild: Failing as PHP 7.4 cannot be found

Tags: php, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have an AWS pipeline established with an EC2 instance deploying a Laravel application on to it. A new package was required that needs PHP7.4.

**What I'm trying to do:**
Simply update the PHP version used within my pipeline which is accepted in the [AWS guideline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html).

**What steps I've taken:**
I updated my `buildspec.yml` file to:

```
  runtime-versions:
    php: 7.4
```

However, I end up with the following error in the log:

[image]

**What I've tried:**
I added pre-build commands to update the repositories (as below)

```
pre_build:
  run-as: ec2-user
  commands:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get upgrade -y
    - apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-zip
    - phpenmod zip
```

Essentially, it looks like the instance cannot find the version of PHP. Has anyone encountered this before and if so, how can I update the version without starting from scratch?

Comment: Odd AWS shows 7.4 as an example in the instructions but under the runtime versions it just lists 7.3. If you update your spec to use the latest version verify it's at least 7.4

Comment: I'm using version: 0.2 in the buildspec.yml. I'll try version: 0.3. Is this what you're referenceing @AaronW?

Comment: No I was referencing the PHP version you specified under runtime-versions to try `php: latest` instead to see if they offer at least version 7.4 yet

Comment: Apologies @AaronW, I should have pointed out. I have also tried "latest". The highest version it's finding is PHP:7.3.9.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - but you would need need to add an extra source repo that contains the 7.4 runtime before trying to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no php 7.4 runtime in CodeBuild Linux curated images. I have requested a document update via GitHub link at bottom of page [1].

For your use case, I would recommend to update the Image of Environment to custom image 'php:7.4.3-cli' which is hosted on Dockerhub to use this image as your build container.

I tested this with a simple buildspec:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - php -v
  build:
    commands:
      - date
```

Result:

```
[Container] 2020/03/05 14:49:57 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2020/03/05 14:49:57 Running command php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 26 2020 12:05:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Ref:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I was sure the version was available after seeing it in the documentation. I'll replace the image with a Docker-hosted one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php 7.4 in build images `Amazon Linux 2 standard:3.0` and `Ubuntu standard:4.0` for more details follow the link below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html